# Post-Newtonian Stress-Energy tensor

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, post-newtonian

I am currently studying Michele Maggiore's book - 'Gravitational Waves: Volume 1: Theory and Experiments'. On pages 245 and 246, each order --- until the second order --- of the stress-energy tensor. The stress-energy tensor may be written as follows:

$$T^{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-g}}\sum_{a} m_{a} \frac{d\tau_{a}}{dt}\frac{dx^{\mu}_{a}}{d\tau_{a}}\frac{dx^{\nu}_{a}}{d\tau_{a}}\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_{a}(t) \right)$$

We know that $$-g = 1 - g_{00}^{(2)} + \sum_{i}g_{ii}^{(2)} = 1 - 4\phi$$ and that $$d\tau_{a}/dt = 1 + \phi.$$ Substituting in the stress-energy tensor we may write:

$$T^{\mu \nu} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{-(1 - 4\phi)}}\sum_{a} m_{a} (1 + \phi)\frac{dx^{\mu}_{a}}{d\tau_{a}}\frac{dx^{\nu}_{a}}{d\tau_{a}}\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_{a}(t) \right)$$

How does one obtain the zero-order and second-order expansion of the stress-energy tensor if there is no $v/c$?

For reference, the zero-order and second-order are the following (for $T^{00}$):

$$T_{(0)}^{00} = \sum_{a \neq b} m_{a}c^{2}\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_{a}(t) \right)$$

$$T_{(2)}^{00} = \sum_{a \neq b} m_{a}(\frac{1}{2}v^{2}_{a}+ \phi c^{2})\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}_{a}(t) \right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$ds^2=c^2d\tau^2= g_{00}c^2dt^2 - g_{ij}dx^idx^j=c^2dt^2\left(1+2\frac{\phi}{c^2}-\frac{1}{c^2}v_iv^i+\cdots\right)$$
where $v^i=dx^i/dt$ and so the correct $\gamma$ factor should be $$\frac{dt}{d\tau}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(1+2\frac{\phi}{c^2}-\frac{1}{c^2}v_iv^i+\cdots\right)}}\approx 1+\frac{\phi}{c^2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2}+\cdots$$
consequently
$$T^{00}\sim mc^2\left(1+\frac{\phi}{c^2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2}+\cdots\right)\delta^{(3)}(x-x_0(t))$$

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question, what happens to the determinant of the metric tensor? Could you expand on that as well, please?

Comment: it remains the same except write $\phi/c^2$ instead of just $\phi$ (I used $\phi=-GM/r$...idk if you missed the 1/c^2 term there or was it included)

Comment: It was not included in the book! (Maybe it’s assumed c = 1). 
The expansion of $1/\sqrt{(-1 + 4\phi/c^2)}$ does not influence the result of T^{00}? I ask since you didn’t consider that in your computations and got the correct result.

Comment: Prolly the book considered $\phi=-GM/rc^2$. You are expanding everything in order of $1/c^2$ so you can't assume $c=1$ here. And yes, I ignored the $1/\sqrt{1-4\phi/c^2}$ term because if you expand it you will get $1+\cdots$ The latter terms are not going to contribute to $T^{00}_{(0)}$ or $T^{00}_{(2)}$ (you can verify it)

Comment: btw a small error : the $\gamma$ factor is $\approx 1-\frac{\phi}{c^2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{v^2}{c^2}+\cdots $